# Wordpress set post status by user role

Tags: wordpress

Looking for function that override default post status for front end entry 
 for custom post type

created custom post type "property"

and custom user type "agent"

While if there is agent posting the property

set property status to "pending"

any idea ... ?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/ try this

Comment: that plugin is grate but now work where post comes through front end

Comment: i have custom post type = "proerty" 
how to add then in role scope